Pythonic way to create a dummy object that does nothing from another class
I have a class Log and I want to create another class NullLog which has all the same method names as Log, but all of its methods are set to the function do_nothing(). That way I can use a NullLog object in place of a Log object to prevent anything from being logged, without any errors occurring from methods that don't exist being called.
I could use inspect.getmembers() as shown here to get all the methods in Log, then use exec() to assign methods with the same names on initialisation of a NullLog object, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Does it have to have only those members, or can return do_nothing for every attribute name?

I'd look at unittest.mock.Mock or unittest.mock.MagicMock . If you really just want a drop-in replacement that won't error, this will do it.

@BoppreH I think returning that for every attribute would be fine.

Why would it even cross your mind to use exec() here?  setattr(NullLog, methodName, do_nothing) in a loop would do the job.

As you desire to dynamically create class you might use type built-in function in its' three-arguments form. Consider following example
class SomeClass:
    x = 100
    def say_this(self):
        print("this")
    def say_that(self):
        print("that")

def do_nothing(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return None

silent_methods = {k:do_nothing for k,v in SomeClass.__dict__.items() if callable(v)}

SilentClass = type("SilentClass", (SomeClass,), silent_methods)

some_obj = SomeClass()
silent_obj = SilentClass()
some_obj.say_this()  # print this
silent_obj.say_this()  # does not print anything
print(silent_obj.x)  # you still can access class attribute so this gives 100

Explanation: I dynamically create class which does inherit from SomeClass, but has all methods (callable attributes) replaced with do_nothing function. Observe that do_nothing accept any number of arguments, so it will not complain even if you provide more arguments that accepted by SomeClass method.
